# Using openmp and fftw on fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp, fftw

I am currently trying to run `fftw` with OpenMP on Fortran but I am having some problems running any programs.

I believe I have installed/configured fftw correctly:

```
./configure --enable-openmp --enable-threads
```

and I seem to have all the correct libraries and files but i cannot get any program to run, I keep getting the error

```
undefined reference to 'fftw_init_threads'
```

The code I use is below:

```
  program trial
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    include "fftw3.f"
    integer :: id, nthreads, void
    integer :: error

    call fftw_init_threads(void)

    !$omp parallel private(id)
    id = omp_get_thread_num()
    write (*,*) 'Hello World from thread', id
    !$omp barrier

    if ( id == 0 ) then
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
      write (*,*) 'There are', nthreads, 'threads'
    end if

    !$omp end parallel
  end program
```

and to run it I do

```
gfortran trial.f90 -I/home/files/include -L/home/files/lib -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -fopenmp
```

It would be greatly appreciated, if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old FORTRAN interface seems not to support OpenMP... I suggest you take the new Fortran 2003 interface. Please note that `fftw_init_threads()` is a function!

You also need to include the `ISO_C_binding` module:

```
  program trial
    use,intrinsic :: ISO_C_binding
    use omp_lib
    implicit none
    include "fftw3.f03"
    integer :: id, nthreads, void
    integer :: error

    void = fftw_init_threads()

    !$omp parallel private(id)
    id = omp_get_thread_num()
    write (*,*) 'Hello World from thread', id
    !$omp barrier

    if ( id == 0 ) then
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()
      write (*,*) 'There are', nthreads, 'threads'
    end if

    !$omp end parallel
  end program
```

Comment: is working now, thank you so much!!    One more question I have if thats ok is that it says i should now call                       void fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int nthreads); Does this mean that i just say call fftw_plan_nthreads(int,nthreads) where int and nthreads are both defined to be integer values, thank you so much

Comment: No, `int nthreads` comes from the C language and it just means that `nthreads` is an integer. Call it with just one number: `call fftw_plan_with_nthreads(int(nthreads,c_int))` (see the bottom of https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/fft-inc.f90 ).

Comment: fantastic, thank you so much. made my life about a million times easier